# How to fix the error: incompatible types: MenuFragment cannot be converted to Fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I;m very much new to fragment activity. I'm working on Fragment activity in which there will be collapsible listview. But I'm facing this error.

My code -

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                // Top Rated fragment activity
                return new MenuFragment();
            case 1:
                // Games fragment activity
                return new BookTableFragment();
            case 2:
                // Movies fragment activity
                return new MyBookingsFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

I tried importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` but still the line **return new MenuFragment();** gives an error **error: incompatible types: MenuFragment cannot be converted to Fragment**

How can I fix this?

Comment: show `MenuFragment`. check there using `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `import android.app.Fragment;` in your MenuFragment and other fragment classes to `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`